# Is this a typo in html5shiv?

Tags: javascript

I just saw html5shiv and found this code:

```
function addStyleSheet(ownerDocument, cssText) {
    var p = ownerDocument.createElement('p'),
        parent = ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || ownerDocument.documentElement;

    p.innerHTML = 'x<style>' + cssText + '</style>';
    return parent.insertBefore(p.lastChild, parent.firstChild);
  }
```

Where `p.innerHTML = 'x<style>' + cssText + '</style>';` is used. Why **x** is used here?

Comment: What happens if you remove it?

Comment: It seems not working if I remove that. (html5 elements are not supported in older browsers)

Comment: I think it has something to do with `X-UA-Compatible`?

Comment: I'm not sure but think it might be for quirk mode...

Comment: Note that `p` isn't inserted into `parent`, but rather `p.lastChild` is inserted (i.e., the `<style>` tag only, not the `x` text). This appears to be handling some strange browser quirk where `innerHTML` won't work with only a `<style>` element, but requires some other text to precede it.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a typo.

According to [question about x](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/commit/dfa3d1e31e930d2daf9da8bdfa450013353dfbe7#commitcomment-7119486) **aFarkas** has made answer

> This is because of a non standard concept of old IE. Similiar to the concept of "has layout" in CSS, they had the concept of scoped and nonscoped elements for rendering with innerHTML.

### aFarkas points to two articles

- http://allofetechnical.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/ies-innerhtml-method-with-script-and-style-tags/
- http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/noscope

### The problem

> When IE converts a string of HTML into a DOM structure, it treats SCRIPT and STYLE differently than any other tags. When it hits one, it checks to see if there are any nodes before it that are “visible.” (Visible very loosely means nodes that will be displayed when the structure is rendered.) If there aren’t any visible nodes before it hits SCRIPT or STYLE, it simply tosses those away and continues processing.